# How to use in multiple inheritance an abstract method

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, systemc

It looks like that there is something that I don't understand about multiple inheritance and abstract methods. I am implementing some hardware functionality in SystemC, with multiple target HWs. I have two different levels of software implementation. The first one is optimized for performance; the second one on its top, has some display, etc. functionality. [Note, in the hardware world "top" refers to the highest level instance which is usually a wrapper or a testbench for the hardware instance]

To actually handle a HW, in scSW I implemented "Hold()". When I want to use it in the higher level (see SW and SW2),
my compiler said

```
error: ‘scHW’ is an ambiguous base of ‘SW’
 struct SW : scSW, HW { virtual bool Holds(){return scHW::Holds();} };
```

and

```
invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘SW2’
     SW2* S2 = new SW2;
                   ^~~
because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘SW2’:
 struct SW2 : scSW, HW {  };
```

It also added:

```
 request for member ‘Holds’ is ambiguous
     std::cerr << S2->Holds();
```

I especially do not see, how can a method be pure and ambiguous, at the same time? What do I wrong and what is the correct way of coding what I want?

```
#include <iostream>
struct Virtual { virtual bool Holds() = 0;};
struct scHW { bool Holds(){return true;}};
struct scSW : scHW, Virtual {};
struct HW : scHW { };
struct HW2 : scHW { virtual bool Holds(){return scHW::Holds();}};
struct SW : scSW, HW { virtual bool Holds(){return scHW::Holds();} };
struct SW2 : scSW, HW {  };

int main()
{
    HW* H = new HW;
    HW2* H2 = new HW2;
    scHW* H1 = new scHW;
    SW* S = new SW;
    SW2* S2 = new SW2;
    std::cerr << S->Holds();
    std::cerr << H->Holds();
    std::cerr << H2->Holds();
    std::cerr << S2->Holds();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this may be more complicated than typical diamond problem

Comment: As a side note, `Holds`'s name suggests it is a getter in general, so you might consider declaring it `const`.

Comment: Also see [How can I avoid the Diamond of Death when using multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137282/608639)

Comment: Tip: don't use variable/type names that differ from language/library names only in case e.g., `Virtual`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen When not using virtual inheritance, it isn't called a diamond

Answer (score 1):

It's pure and ambiguous at the same time because name lookup and virtual function overriding are mostly orthogonal mechanisms. You see here:

```
struct scSW : scHW, Virtual {};
struct HW : scHW { };
```

Looking up `Holds` in `scSW` will go into two different base class sub-object ([as explained on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54512860/817643)). The `scHW` and `Virtual` bases. As such, the lookup is ambiguous. Those are two **different** functions in two different classes that are referred to by the same identifier.

Which not quite so coincidentally is also why `Virtual::Holds` is not overridden in `scSW`. The member from `scHW` is unrelated. There is no virtual function overrider in `scSW`, so that class remains abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might not want multiple inheritance, and just do:

```
 struct scHW : Virtual { virtual bool Holds(){return true;}};
 struct scSW : scHW {};
 ...
```

that way `scHW` isn't abstract and can be instantiated.

Comment: I definitely want multiple inheritance: Virtual provides the abstract handling,  and scSW the physical one. The abstract function enables other methods of scSW to implement handling a concrete HW without knowing the details of the hardware, in this case different hardware units. In the way you proposed, Virtual provides a 'default' method, and the programmer of the hardware driver is not forced to implement (override) the method.